# How to find the tilted angle from a set of hanging masses between two pulleys?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors, physics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows three masses tied to a central one which
>   is hanging with respect of a floor. Find the angle so that the system
>   remains in static equilibrium:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&50^{\circ}\\
2.&80^{\circ}\\
3.&60^{\circ}\\
4.&70^{\circ}\\
5.&45^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

What I've attempted to do was to equate what it is on the vertical components for the tension of the string and for the horizontal components.

What I obtained was as follows:

In the vertical:

$Mg\cos 50^{\circ}+mg\cos \alpha = mg$

In the horizontal:

$Mg\sin 50^{\circ} = mg\sin\alpha$

Therefore:

$M=\frac{m\sin\alpha}{\sin 50^{\circ}}$

If I do insert this in the equation for the vertical components. I'm obtaining the following:

$\frac{mg\sin\alpha}{\sin 50^{\circ}}\cos 50^{\circ}+mg\cos \alpha = mg$

Dividing by similar terms and multiplying by \sin 50^{\circ} to tall:

$\sin\alpha\cos 50^{\circ}+\cos \alpha\sin50^{\circ}=\sin 50$

This is reduced to:

$\sin(\alpha+50^{\circ})=\sin 50^{\circ}$

Therefore $\alpha =0$

But this doesn't make sense. Could it be that I'm missinterpreting something. Can somebody help me here?.

Answer (score 1):

From $\sin\alpha\cos 50^{\circ}+\cos \alpha\sin50^{\circ}=\sin 50^{\circ}$, square both sides:

$$\sin^2\alpha\cos^2 50^{\circ}+2\sin\alpha\cos 50^{\circ}\cos \alpha\sin50^{\circ}+\cos^2 \alpha\sin^250^{\circ}=\sin^2 50^{\circ}$$
Reconcile the right-most terms:
$$\sin^2\alpha\cos^2 50^{\circ}+2\sin\alpha\cos 50^{\circ}\cos \alpha\sin50^{\circ}-\sin^2 \alpha\sin^250^{\circ}=0$$
Divide through by $\sin^2\alpha$, which is acceptable if we assume the obvious from the context that $\sin\alpha\neq0$:
$$\cos^2 50^{\circ}+2\cos 50^{\circ}\cot \alpha\sin50^{\circ}-\sin^250^{\circ}=0$$
Now you can solve for $\cot\alpha$:
$$\cot\alpha=\frac{\sin^250^{\circ}-\cos^250^{\circ}}{2\sin50^{\circ}\cos 50^{\circ}}$$

And use trig identities:
$$\cot\alpha=\frac{-\cos100^{\circ}}{\sin100^{\circ}}=-\cot100^{\circ}=\cot(180^{\circ}-100^{\circ})=\cot(80^{\circ})$$

So $80^\circ$ is one solution. Add an integer multiple of $180^\circ$ and you preserve tangents and cotangents, so you can get other algebraic solutions that way. But only $80^\circ$ makes sense in context.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to reach the exact same conclusion as "$\sin(\alpha+50^{\circ})=\sin 50^{\circ}$ has several solutions, only one of which makes sense in this context"

Comment: @Arthur I don't disagree. My sense was this is the kind of thing that OP was thinking of/looking for.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for that. That was exactly the kind of approach I was having in mind. However I'm stuck in the final line of your equality. How do I get $80^{\circ}$ in $\cot\alpha=-\cot(100^{\circ})$?. For the equality to be preserved it meant that the cotangent has to be negative, so it has to lie in the second and the fourth quadrant, right?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell  $-\cot(x)=\cot(180^\circ-x)$ is just a trig identity, which I used with $x=100^\circ$. $x$ and $180^\circ-x$ are symmetric angles with respect to $90^\circ$, so the corresponding lines through the origin have negative slopes. (And $\cot$ gives the reciprocal of that slope.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin(\alpha+50^{\circ})=\sin 50^{\circ}$ has solutions other than $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too dumb or what?. I didn't noticed. But I need another hint. Please. Where should I start looking?. Uh oh. :(

Comment: I overlooked the fact that the sine has the same values in the second quadrant, thus $\sin(50)=\sin(130^{\circ})$ therefore $130=50+x$ and $x=80^{\circ}$ which would be the second option. But what would be the other formal method to establish this? Can a quadratic equation be formed?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Your second comment here is more than formal enough in my opinion. The fact that trigonometric equations have multiple solutions is as well-established as the fact that quadratic equations have several solutions, so there is no need to try to translate it over to that realm.